# React-navigation: how to style a big middle button in tab navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have this requirement. To make tab navigation with this exact appearance:

[image: This is the goal]
I had no problem styling the tab bar with the gradient and the buttons. I created my own custom one with this code:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  (... routes here)
}, {
  initialRouteName: "Inspiration",
  tabBarComponent: props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />
})
```

But now I'm having trouble with the middle button. My bar looks like this:

[image: This is how it looks now]

If I remove the custom tab bar removing this line:

```
tabBarComponent: props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />
```

Then now my middle button looks how it should, but of course, all of the other styles are missing:

[image: Not close enough]

This is how my BottomTabBar component looks right now:

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { TabBarBottomProps, NavigationRoute } from "react-navigation";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

const iconBag = require("./images/bag.png");

export default function BottomTabBar(props: TabBarBottomProps) {
  const {
    renderIcon,
    getLabelText,
    activeTintColor,
    inactiveTintColor,
    onTabPress,
    onTabLongPress,
    getAccessibilityLabel,
    navigation
  } = props;

  const { routes, index: activeRouteIndex } = navigation.state;

  function renderTabBarButton(routeIndex, route) {
    const isRouteActive = routeIndex === activeRouteIndex;
    const tintColor = isRouteActive ? activeTintColor : inactiveTintColor;

    if (route.key == "Bag")
      return <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={iconBag} />;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={routeIndex}
        style={styles.tabButton}
        onPress={() => onTabPress({ route })}
        onLongPress={() => onTabLongPress({ route })}
        accessibilityLabel={getAccessibilityLabel({ route })}
      >
        {renderIcon({ route, focused: isRouteActive, tintColor })}
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>{getLabelText({ route })}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  return (
    <LinearGradient colors={["#FFFFFF", "#DEDEDE"]} style={styles.container}>
      {routes.map((route, routeIndex) => renderTabBarButton(routeIndex, route))}
    </LinearGradient>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 60,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#C4C4C4"
  },
  tabButton: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  tabText: {
    fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
    fontSize: 11,
    color: "#454545",
    marginTop: 1
  }
});
```

What can I do? Any help will be really much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

---

You can try my solution

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
Top: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./src/assets/ic_list.png')}
        style={{width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: tintColor}}
      />
    ),
  },
},

New: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./src/assets/ic_clock.png')}
        style={{width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: tintColor}}
      />
    ),
  },
},
Ask: { // big plus icon in the middle
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 20, // space from bottombar
          height: 58,
          width: 58,
          borderRadius: 58,
          backgroundColor: '#5a95ff',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image
          source={require('./src/assets/ic_add_24.png')}
          style={{
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            tintColor: '#f1f6f9',
            alignContent: 'center',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    ),
  },
},
Show: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./src/assets/ic_notification.png')}
        style={{width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: tintColor}}
      />
    ),
  },
},
Jobs: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./src/assets/ic_person.png')}
        style={{width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: tintColor}}
      />
    ),
  },
},
},
{
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#FF6F00',
  inactiveTintColor: '#8997B0',
  showIcon: true,
  showLabel: false,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#f1f6f9',
  },
},
},
);
```

Comment: This is awesome, it saved my day! thanks for the great solution!

Comment: Thanks but when i click to this icon "middle big plus icon" it does not navigate me to his screen! specially in android !

Comment: @OliverD this is just UI showcase. In order to navigate to screen, you must implement yourself

Comment: The issue here is not navigation. The part of the button that is above the bar is not clickable. Even if I surround the whole View with a Touchable. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I made this bottom tab with react native. I think your design is very simple. My code sample will help you I think.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Text } from 'native-base';

import Featured from './featured';
import AboutUs from './about_us';
import Shop from './shop';
import Booking from './booking';
import Settings from './settings';
import styles from './styles';

import star from './../../assets/images/icons/star.png';
import star_check from './../../assets/images/icons/star_check.png';
import about from './../../assets/images/icons/about.png';
import about_check from './../../assets/images/icons/about_check.png';
import book from './../../assets/images/icons/book.png';
import check from './../../assets/images/icons/check.png';
import shop from './../../assets/images/icons/shop.png';
import shop_check from './../../assets/images/icons/shop_check.png';
import more from './../../assets/images/icons/more.png';
import more_check from './../../assets/images/icons/more_check.png';

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Featured: {
            screen: Featured,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Featured',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                        <View style={styles.tab}>
                            <Image source={focused? star_check : star} style={styles.icon} />
                            <Text style={[styles.name, {color: tintColor}]}>Kampanjer</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
            }
        },
        AboutUs: {
            screen: AboutUs,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'About Us',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                            <View style={styles.tab}>
                                <Image source={focused? about_check : about} style={styles.icon} />
                                <Text style={[styles.name, {color: tintColor}]}>Om oss</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
            }
        },
        Booking: {
            screen: Booking,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'MIN SALONG',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                            <View style={styles.book}>
                                <Image source={focused? check : book} style={styles.book_icon} />
                            </View>
                        )
            }
        },
        Shop: {
            screen: Shop,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Shop',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                            <View style={styles.tab}>
                                <Image source={focused? shop_check : shop} style={styles.icon} />
                                <Text style={[styles.name, {color: tintColor}]}>Shop</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
            }
        },
        Settings: {
            screen: Settings,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'More',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                            <View style={styles.tab}>
                                <Image source={focused? more_check : more} style={styles.icon} />
                                <Text style={[styles.name, {color: tintColor}]}>Inställningar</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
            }
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Featured',
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#80A0AB',
            inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
            showLabel: false,
            style: {
                height: 60,
                backgroundColor: '#485155'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Abel-Regular'
            }
        }  
    }
);

export default createStackNavigator({Tabs}, {headerMode: "none"});
```

Comment: Thank you sir!
The problem is: I need to add the gradient to the bar, and that's only possible if I create my own tab bar. Then when I create my tab bar, the middle button doesn't display correctly

Comment: In tabBarOptions you can set gradient background I think. Then you have to custom tabBarIcon with react component.

Comment: Can you please share styles as well? Thanks

Comment: @ProDev could you please share the style for the middle button, thank you

Comment: Without the styles of the book icon, this response does not seem to be very helpful... Did anyone figure it out?

Comment: @jhuesos is right, without the styles you can't tell what makes the solution work.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
<Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: 'red',
               // activeBackgroundColor:'#000',
                //inactiveBackgroundColor:'red',
                labelStyle: {
                     position: 'absolute',
                     top: constants.vh(35),
                    fontSize:constants.vh(18),
                }
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name='Home' //bottom tab for Home
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                        let iconName;
                        iconName = focused ? constants.images.bottomHome : constants.images.bottomHome //for icon or image
                        return (
                            <View>
                                <Image source={iconName} style={{ width: constants.vw(40), height: constants.vh(25) ,position:'absolute',right:constants.vw(-20),bottom:constants.vh(-5)}} resizeMode="contain" />
                            </View>
                        )
                    }
                }}
                component={HomeScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried this

```
    import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {IntroScreen, MeOneScreen} from '../screens/auth';
import { Text} from '../components/theme';
import {TabIcon} from './TabIcons';
import {Box, Center} from 'native-base';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#FDFEFF',
          height: 60,
          paddingVertical: 5,
        },

        tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
          return (
            <Center>
              <TabIcon type={route.name} color={color} height={24} width={24} />
              <Text
                variant="grey"
                fontSize={10}
                color={focused ? '#A6CE39' : 'grey'}>
                {route.name}
              </Text>
              <Box h={0.5} w={4} bg={focused ? '#A6CE39' : 'transparent'} />
            </Center>
          );
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#A6CE39',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#888888',
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={IntroScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Wallet" component={MeOneScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={IntroScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            return (
              <Box position="absolute" bottom={5} bg="#F5F8FA" rounded="full">
                <Box
                  borderColor="#fff"
                  borderWidth={2}
                  elevation={5}
                  zIndex={5}
                  p={4}
                  m={2}
                  rounded="full"
                  bg="#A6CE39">
                  <TabIcon type={'Home'} color={color} height={24} width={24} />
                </Box>
              </Box>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Message" component={IntroScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={MeOneScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default TabNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add one style property in your bag tab Image style:
`zIndex: 10`