# Middle tab button using react-navigation version 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I need to add a middle button to the app's tab navigator. 
[It's easy to implement this feature using react-navigation 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766486/react-navigation-how-to-style-a-big-middle-button-in-tab-navigation), However, react-navigation 5, has a different structure and I couldn't find anyway to insert a custom button or component inside navigator.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = props => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={FirstScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={SecondScreen} />

                {...here...}

                <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={ThirdScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Screen4" component={ForthScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

What can I do? Any help will be really much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the navigationOptions pros inside the Tab.screen tag and create your own custom view same as old version.